# Excluding tables from "show tables" in a scripted mysqldump

Tags: mysql, bash

I would like to update the following bash script, which individually dumps each table in a given schema:

```
for t in $(mysql -NBA -h db_host -u db_user -pdb_pass db_name -e 'show tables')
do
mysqldump -h db_host -u db_user -pdb_pass db_name $t > db_name.$t.sql
```

to exclude some tables that do not need to be picked up by this script.  This is what I mean:

```
for t in $(mysql -NBA -h db_host -u db_user -pdb_pass db_name -e 'show tables where `Tables_in_db_name` not like 'table1' and `Tables_in_db_name` not like 'table2'')
do
mysqldump -h db_host -u db_user -pdb_pass db_name $t > db_name.$t.sql
```

The sql is fine in itself, but I can't get it to run inside the -e command.  Obviously in this example, the problem is the -e command's opening and closing apostrophes.  I have tried:

- Using quotes instead of apostrophes.  ie -e "show tables where etc"
- Using slashes on the internal apostrophes.  ie \'table1\'

With no success.  Does anybody know how to accommodate apostrophes and back ticks within these confines?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The SQL is fine in itself, but I can't get it to run inside the `-e` command. Obviously in this example, the problem is the `-e` command's opening and closing apostrophes.

Right. I assume it will be necessary to escape the backticks. After a short test it seems that

```
mysql -NBA -h ${DB_HOST} -u "${DB_USER}" -p" ${DB_PASS}" ${DB_NAME} -e "SHOW TABLES WHERE \`Tables_in_${DB_NAME}\` NOT LIKE 'table%'"
```

is working.